# What is tuning in machine learning?

Tags: performance, machine-learning

I am a novice learner of machine learning and am confused by tuning.
What is the purpose of tuning in machine learning? To select the best parameters for an algorithm?
How does tuning works?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. For general questions about machine learning methodologies etc, please refer to the description of the [tag:machine-learning] tag

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Without getting into a technical demonstration that would seem appropriate for Stackoverflow, here are some general thoughts. Essentially, one can argue that the ultimate goal of machine learning is to make a machine system that can automatically build models from data without requiring tedious and time consuming human involvement. As you recognize, one of the difficulties is that learning algorithms (eg. decision trees, random forests, clustering techniques, etc.) require you to set parameters before you use the models (or at least to set constraints on those parameters). How you set those parameters can depend on a whole host of factors. That said, your goal, is usually to set those parameters to so optimal values that enable you to complete a learning task in the best way possible. Thus, tuning an algorithm or machine learning technique, can be simply thought of as process which one goes through in which they optimize the parameters that impact the model in order to enable the algorithm to perform the best (once, of course you have defined what "best" actual is).

To make it more concrete, here are a few examples. If you take a machine learning algorithm for clustering like KNN, you will note that you, as the programmer, must specify the number of K's in your model (or centroids), that are used. How do you do this? You tune the model. There are many ways that you can do this. One of these can be trying many many different values of K for a model, and looking to understand how the inter and intra group error as you very the number of K's in your model.

As another example, let us consider say support vector machine (SVM) classication. SVM classification requires an initial learning phase in which the training data are used
to adjust the classication parameters. This really refers to an initial parameter tuning phase where you, as the programmer, might try to "tune" the models in order to achieve high quality results.

Now, you might be thinking that this process can be difficult, and you are right. In fact, because of the difficulty of determining what optimal model parameters are, some researchers use complex learning algorithms before experimenting adequately with simpler alternatives with better tuned parameters.

Comment: is it possible that i train a deep NN with an initial large supervised database and then fine-tune it with an unsupervised target database? someone says that do. can you explain how? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the abstract sense of machine learning, tuning is working with / "learning from" variable data based on some parameters which have been identified to affect *system performance* as evaluated by some appropriate<sup>1</sup> metric. Improved performance reveals which parameter settings are more favorable (tuned) or less favorable (untuned).

Translating this into common sense, tuning is essentially selecting the best parameters for an algorithm to optimize its performance given a working environment such as hardware, specific workloads, etc. And tuning in machine learning is an automated process for doing this.

For example, there is no such thing as a "perfect set" of optimizations for all deployments of an Apache web server. A sysadmin learns from the data "on the job" so to speak and optimizes their own Apache web server configuration as appropriate for its specific environment. Now imagine an automated process for doing this same thing, i.e., a system that can learn from data on its own, which is the definition of machine learning. A system that tunes its own parameters in such a data-based fashion would be an instance of tuning in machine learning.

> <sup>1</sup> *System performance* as mentioned here, can be many things, and is much more general than the computers themselves. Performance can be measured by minimizing the number of adjustments needed for a self-driving car to parallel park, or the number of false predictions in autocomplete; or it could be maximizing the time an average visitor spends on a website based on advertisement dimensions, or the number of in-app purchases in Candy Crush.
>
> Cleverly defining what "performance" means in a way that is both meaningful and measurable is key in a successful machine learning system.

Answer (score 1):

A little pedantic but just want to clarify that a **parameter** is something that is internal to the model (you do not set it). What you are referring to is a **hyperparameter**.

Different machine learning algorithms have a set of hyperparameters that can be adjusted to improve performance (or make it worse). The most common and maybe simplest way to find the best hyperparameter is through what's known as a grid search (searching across a set of values).

Some examples of hyperparameters include the number of trees for a random forest algorithm, or a value for regularization.

**Important note:** hyperparameters must be tuned on a separate set of training data. Lot's of new folks to machine learning will modify the hyperparameters on the training data set until they see the best performance on the test dataset. You are essentially overfitting the hyperparameter by doing this.